# Finding the best pass by calculating the maximum value in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have three numpys as follows. The numpy named `mat` describes a result of certain calculation operation. The numpy named  `pos` describes the column of `mat` and the numpy named `prv` describes the rows of `mat`.

```
prv = np.array(['P','N','U'])
pos = np.array(['E','P','T','N','U'])
mat = np.array([[9,1,2,3,4],
                [4,2,1,2,1],
                [2,7,5,8,9]])
```

Need to find the maximum value in each column and according to that result build a new numpy that will describes the transition from `prv` to `pos`.

That is, according to the above data the result should be:

```
[['P','E'],
 ['U','P'],
 ['U','T'],
 ['U','N'],
 ['U','U']]
```

**Explanation**: The highest value of column 0 in `mat` (the column represented by `E`) placed in row 0 (the row represented by `P`). Thus, the best ruth to `E` would be from `P` (the first row in `rsult` would be `['P', 'E']`). In row `N` there is no maximum values, therefore there will be no path results.
In contrast, the line `U` has four results of maximum values. In column 1 (`P`), in column 2 ( `T`), in column 3 (`N`) and in column 4 (`U`).

Note: In case of equality, it doesn't matter which value is selected (but only one value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is amounts to a simple relabeling of `argmax`:

```
np.c_[prv[mat.argmax(0)],pos]

# array([['P', 'E'],
#        ['U', 'P'],
#        ['U', 'T'],
#        ['U', 'N'],
#        ['U', 'U']], dtype='<U1')
```